# How to cut (`trim`) audio with timestamps Python

Tags: python, audio, mp3, wav, pydub

Ok everyone this is a very very very hard problem. I've spent 3 days already and this feels like a millennium prize math problem.

Ok so I have a .ttml of timestamps where I analyzed a mp4 video and stripped subtitles. The assumption is that these timestamps are actual audio in the video (basically these timestamps are audio in the video)

Here is how the .ttml looks like

```
<p begin="00:00:04.550" end="00:00:06.920" style="s2">hello bob</p>
<p begin="00:00:07.500" end="00:00:10.075" style="s2">hey man lets play hockey/p>
<p begin="00:00:10.366" end="00:00:14.100" style="s2">sure</p>
<p begin="00:00:16.210" end="00:00:18.980" style="s2">actually I cannot</p>
<p begin="00:00:21.260" end="00:00:23.230" style="s2">Ok maybe next time</p>
```

I used datetime module to calculate the difference of all the timestamps and sum them up.

```
def calculate_time(file_name: str):
print("WTF")
diff = datetime.timedelta()

file_text = "".join(open(file_name).readlines())
p_tags = Selector(text=file_text).xpath("//p").getall()
for ptag in p_tags:
    begin = Selector(text=ptag).xpath("//@begin").get()
    endie = Selector(text=ptag).xpath("//@end").get()

    start_time = dt.strptime(begin, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
    endie_time = dt.strptime(endie, '%H:%M:%S.%f')

    diff += endie_time-start_time

  return diff


for fname in glob.glob(r"temp_results/*.ttml"):

    current_time = calculate_time(file_name=fname)
```

The above code says that my total timestamp(audio actually spoken in the video) is **7:09 minutes**

Now here is where things get really hard. So The mp4 where I got these timestamps/subs from I converted it to a wav file. The wav file audio is **9 minutes long**

How do I edit the wav file so that it actually takes the audio from the mp4  or itself and **only includes the audio specified in from the timestamp file??**

I tried using Pydub https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub but I only see this, I need to somehow subtract the timestamps or convert to miliseconds??
    from pydub import AudioSegment

```
 audio = AudioSegment.from_wav("never_gonna_give_you_up.wav")
 ten_seconds = 10 * 1000


 new_audio = audio[-5000:] .  #5000 = timestamp datetime object?
```